# Issue Installing the AWS SAM CLI on Mac M2

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, aws-sam-cli

I am trying to install via Command line the AWS SAM CLI on MacBook Pro with M2 processor. I followed the steps described in the [official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/install-sam-cli.html#install-sam-cli-troubleshooting), in order:

1. Download the package *aws-sam-cli-macos-arm64.pkg* for arm64
2. Run the command: `sudo installer -pkg path-to-pkg-installer/name-of-pkg-installer -target /`

Once the password is entered, this message appears:

```
installer: This package requires Rosetta 2 to be installed.
                Please install Rosetta 2 and then try again.
                    `sudo softwareupdate --install-rosetta`

installer: Error - AWS SAM CLI can't be installed on this computer.
```

It seems strange that it needs Rosetta to be installed on Mac cause I have downloaded the ARM version. Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: Old post but the official package still requires Rosetta to be installed. It's almost 2024 and still!! Here's a thread on GitHub: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/7252 regarding the same issue. Anyways, you can use brew to install aws cli w/o Rosetta

Comment: Brew version is not supported anymore, AWS recommends its package, but if these issues happen, it would be still the best option.